# Django filter - Hardcode timezone in url filter parameters

Tags: django, django-filter, django-timezone

I use django filters backend along with Django rest for building a rest api. At certain endpoints the user can filter the request by datetime so this for example

```
/api/api_endpoint_x/?time_start=2015-11-20 11:22:15.160983
```

would form a valid request. Using Django's timezone support with `USE_TZ=True` all incoming datetime requests are being treated as being in end user's local time. For example if that request is coming from Berlin then the filtering will happen upon `2015-11-20 10:22:15.160983` since Berlin time is GMT+1. Is there a way to hardcode a timezone in the request so that the filtering mechanism would make use of the explicitly specified timezone?

I know I can manually inspect the query parameters and make sense out of those and then perform the filtering, but I am investigating the possibility that this functionality is already implemented inside `django-filter`.

For example can I use something like that

```
/api/api_endpoint_x/?time_start=2015-11-20 11:22:15.160983+00:00
```

?